# In Google Docs under script control, can a paragraph inserted automatically after the insertion of a table be addressed programmatically?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs-api

I have a Google Docs document with a PARAGRAPH followed by a TABLE followed by a TABLE. Visually there is a PARAGRAPH between the two TABLEs. Programatically, however, using the following code, the run log demonstrates that there is no PARAGRAPH, viz

```
[1] PARAGRAPH {'LEFT_TO_RIGHT' : true, 'LINE_SPACING' : 1.15, 'SPACING_AFTER' : 0, 'SPACING_BEFORE' : 0, 'INDENT_FIRST_LINE' : 0, 'INDENT_END' : 0, 'INDENT_START' : 0} 
[1/1] TEXT {} perth influencer
[2] TABLE {'BORDER_WIDTH' : 1, 'BORDER_COLOR' : '#000000'} 
[3] TABLE {'BORDER_WIDTH' : 1, 'BORDER_COLOR' : '#000000'} Keyword Research Volume
...
```

According to the Google Apps Script documentation for [appendTable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#appendtable):

> This method will also append an empty paragraph after the table, since Google Docs documents cannot end with a table.

This paragraph can be seen with the eyes but the script as it stands cannot "see" it. That is, stepping through the child elements of the document's body fails to detect the presence of the automatically-inserted paragraph. This is a problem because I want to reduce the point size of that paragraph.

This may be a known limitation of Google Docs via Google Apps Script. Or it may be my bad code, so below are the functions that I base my assertion on. They do nothing other than report on what they find but even so, maybe I'm missing something.

The output above was generated by coding `LogChildren` with a parameter of type `GoogleAppsScript.Document.Body` and referring to the body of the generated document.

```js
String.prototype.quoted = function () {
  return  "'" + this.replace(/'/g,"\\'") + "'";
}

Number.prototype.quoted = function () {
  return String(this);
}

Boolean.prototype.quoted = function () {
    return this ? "true" : "false";
}

function getInnerText(child) {
    switch (child.getType().toString()) {
        case "BODY_SECTION":
            return child.asBody().getText();
            break;
        case "EQUATION":
            return child.asEquation().getText();
            break;
        case "EQUATION_FUNCTION":
            return child.asEquationFunction().getText();
            break;
        case "FOOTER_SECTION":
            return child.asFooterSection().getText();
            break;
        case "FOOTNOTE_SECTION":
            return child.asFootnoteSection().getText();
            break;
        case "HEADER_SECTION":
            return child.asHeaderSection().getText();
            break;
        case "LIST_ITEM":
            return child.asListItem().getText();
            break;
        case "PARAGRAPH":
            return "";
            break;
        case "TABLE":
            return child.asTable().getText();
            break;
        case "TABLE_CELL":
            return child.asTableCell().getText();
            break;
        case "TABLE_OF_CONTENTS":
            return child.asTableOfContents().getText();
            break;
        case "TABLE_ROW":
            return child.asTableRow().getText();
            break;
        case "TEXT":
            return child.asText().getText();
            break;
        case "PAGE_BREAK":
            return "";
            break;
        case "INLINE_IMAGE":
            return child.asInlineImage().getLinkUrl();
            break;
        default:
            return child.asText().getText();
            break;
    }
}
function getStyles(child) {
    const attribs = child.getAttributes();
    const attribList = [];
    for (let att in attribs) {
        try {
            if (null !== attribs[att])
                attribList.push(att.quoted() + " : " + attribs[att].quoted());
        }
        catch (E) { }
    }
    return "{" + attribList.join(", ") + "}";
}
function LogChild(index, child) {
    Logger.log("[%s] %s %s %s", index, child.getType().toString(), getStyles(child), getInnerText(child));
}
function LogChildren(body) {
    function LogDeeper(cc, child) {
        const childCount = child.getNumChildren();
        for (let c = 0; c < childCount; c++) {
            LogChild(String(cc) + "/" + String(c + 1), child.getChild(c));
        }
    }
    const childCount = body.getNumChildren();
    for (let c = 0; c < childCount; c++) {
        const child = body.getChild(c);
        LogChild(String(c + 1), child);
        if (isParagraph(child)) {
            LogDeeper(c + 1, child.asParagraph());
        }
        else if (isListItem(child)) {
            LogDeeper(c + 1, child.asListItem());
        }
    }
}
function isPageBreak(elem) {
    return elem.getType() === DocumentApp.ElementType.PAGE_BREAK;
}
function isText(elem) {
    return elem.getType() === DocumentApp.ElementType.TEXT;
}
function isParagraph(elem) {
    return elem.getType() === DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH;
}
function isListItem(elem) {
    return elem.getType() === DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM;
}
function isTable(elem) {
    return elem.getType() === DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE;
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `it doesn't not appear to be addressable`. Can I ask you about `addressable` you expect? And also, can I ask you about the detail of your issue and your script?

Comment: *since Google Docs documents cannot end with a table.* That would simply mean there needs to be a table at the very end of your document and not between the tables.

Comment: @Tanaike I have attempted to clarify my description

Comment: @TheMaster My issue is that the script has detected two tables one after the other, but my eyes can see a paragraph between them which Google Docs has automatically inserted. So either my script has missed something (which is entirely possible) or there's some disconnect between Docs UI and Docs via Script (which is less possible but has been known to occur).

Comment: @bugmagnet Check the [docs-api tester](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get) and see if there really is a paragraph between the tables. Preferably post the retrieved json  here.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your question, if your situation is the same with [this](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/8e018892ebb417779e9a7fedfc6a4a7d), it might be required to use Google Docs API. If I misunderstood about it, I apologize.

Comment: @TheMaster using the docs-api tester I can "see" the intervening paragraph. I've also managed to do a batchUpdate to change its height. If you post that direction as a solution, I will give it the big green tick.

Comment: @Tanaike yes, as TheMaster also points out, the Docs API is the way to go. Thank you both for gifting me of your precious time

Comment: Great. Added a answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [google-docs-api](/questions/tagged/google-docs-api) 's [Document#get](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get) to retrieve the document structure and if there is a intervening paragraph recorded between the two tables, issue [UpdateParagraphStyleRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#updateparagraphstylerequest) to modify that paragraph.

You can access the api from apps script through [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/docs)

Comment: Exactly what I'm doing now. Thanks again.